# Перенос сайта на сервер, background-image

Tags: html

Я писал сайт на asp.net (+ html). Запускался он на локальном сервере. Все было отлично, но когда я загрузил сайт на хостинг, то background-image не сработало. Я понял, что причина в том, что неправильно (для хостинга) указан путь. Как мне поступить?

```
<div class="header" style="font-size: 30px; background-image: url('/САЙТ/Pictures/MP900439412.JPG')">
```

Comment: Нужно удалить в пути САЙТ/ . Эта директория отсутствует на сервере.

Comment: Как вариант - на локальном сервере зачастую игнорируется регистр расширения файла, т.е. проверьте, чтоб изображение MP900439412.JPG, было именно JPG, а не jpg. А еще лучше изменить расширение картинок в нижний регистр (и в CSS соответственно)

Answer (score 1):

Указывайте путь от корня сайта или относительно файла с шаблоном. Т.е. со слешем браузер ищет папки начиная от корня хоста.

Answer (score 0):

Я пишу так:

```
background: #D2EDFF url('/images/bg_page.jpg') left top repeat;
```

Данный стиль применяется для тега BODY - выполняется из любой вложенной папки, а также независим от префикса WWW.

Comment: А для чего #D2EDFF

Comment: Задает цвет фона пока грузится картинка

Comment: А когда загрузилась цвет уходит?

Comment: Да, цвет уходит

Comment: Цвет-то по умолчанию в разных браузерах разный, можно transparent (прозрачный) написать, но IE не поддержит прозрачность - белый будет

Comment: Цвет можно вообще не писать.

Comment: @welcomemyaltai, куда "цвет уходит"? В какие края? ))) Никуда он не уход, просто располагается слоем ниже фонового изображения. Если для изображения указан параметр no-repeat и блок будет больше изображения, то фон "вернётся" ;)

Comment: Да, @Deonis, конечно ни куда не уходит, но слоем ниже располагается, я приводил пример с repeat для body, потому выразился так, как было в вопросе. Но, если картинка, например, рыжая, то и цвет задать нужно около того, чтобы цвет страницы не мелькал перед пользователем!